# How add middleware for all responses? (express.js)

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

My goal to check all 200 status responses and check data if data null I have to change this request to  404 error. Is possible to do it in express?

setting

```
app.use("/api/tobaccos", tobaccos);

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.message);
});
```

api:

```
router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("GET TOBACCO:" + req.params.id);

  await Tobacco.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(tobacco => res.status(200).json({ status: "success", data: tobacco }))
    .catch(error => res.status(404).json({
      status: "fail",
      msg: "Tobacco not found!",
      code: "error.tobaccoNotFound"
    }));

});
```

I'm trying to add middleware for like this, but it doesn't work

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.message);
});
```

or this doesn't work

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.status(404).send('what???');
});
```

What is wrong? Is it possible?

Comment: Have you read through http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use?

Comment: yep. But still can't find how to get data inside this method next

Answer (score -1):

you can use this

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.log('err: ', err);
    res.status(err.hasOwnProperty('status') ? err.status : 500);
    res.json({
        message: err.hasOwnProperty('errors') ? err.errors : err.toString()
    });
});
```

any error thrown by catch block it will handle that

Comment: I don't have an error. Middleware is about adding code to any part of system

Comment: i am answering for this **app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.message);
});**